# How to deal with this error AVAudioSessionErrorCodeMissingEntitlement?

Tags: ios, audio, entitlements, ios10, callkit

I'm trying to integrate with iOS10's CallKit, however when I'm trying to initialize the audio session after accept a phone call, this "AudioUnitInitialize" API will throw out this error "AVAudioSessionErrorCodeMissingEntitlement".
According to the document, it's just one line explanation:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudiosessionerrorcode/avaudiosessionerrorcodemissingentitlement

How should I update the entitlement for support this? Does any body has any experience?

Comment: I've tried with add a entitlement of "Inter-App-Auido", however it seems not really help, (The "Audio" playing in background mode is already added before).  Somehow this exception doesn't happen for every time, it has nearly 10% to initialize the audio session without any problem.  Looks like a SDK issue of this beta version?

Comment: This also happens on Beta 4, so I filed a radar, it will probably be duped but in any case: http://www.openradar.me/27674736

Comment: It also happens in Beta 5 and Beta 6 :(

Comment: Seeing this still in beta 7.

Comment: Any news after release? It still happens for me in 10.0

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this issue in iOS10 Beta 6, and was able to resolve it by moving the "AudioUnitInitialize" API from the `performAnswerCallAction:` method (as implemented in SpeakerBox) to the `init` routine of the ProviderDelegate.

By moving initialization earlier in the lifecycle of the ProviderDelegate, somehow the 'entitlement' problem is avoided.

Comment: Thanks. It also work for me. Btw, can you handle 'Call Fail' button or don't display native UI when the call fail?

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded Apple's [Speakerbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/Speakerbox/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app to examine the entitlements and background modes used for CallKit.

It looks like they add the Background Modes -> voice over IP entitlement and the "App provides Voice over IP services" key to the app's Info.plist:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
    <string>voip</string>
</array>
```

It also adds the `INStartAudioCallIntent` key to `NSUserActivityTypes` and the following Microphone Usage Description:

```
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) uses the Microphone for call audio</string>
<key>NSCallKitUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) makes and receives calls</string>
<key>NSUserActivityTypes</key>
<array>
    <string>INStartAudioCallIntent</string>
</array>
```

Comment: Hi JAL,  Thanks very much for the reply, however this won't really help, before I post this question, I've already test with this "Speakbox" sample app, the result is it also throw the same exception when initialize the audio session. (It's in the "AudioController.mm", "XThrowIfError(AudioUnitInitialize(_rioUnit)...". If you put a break point in the catch block for this line, you will see it throws exception more than 80%).